# exe still busy after QProcess.waitForFinishand and can't be removed

Tags: windows, qt

I have a visual c++ redistributable installer exe in a resource file. File is extracted, moved to %TEMP%, run with QProcess and removed after process ends. The problem I have is that file removal fails with "Permission denied" even with escalated privileges. It seems that it is caused by file still being used by something (busy) because it starts working if I add a 1 second delay before removal.

```
QFile vcredistResource2015(":\\data\\vc_redist.x86.exe");
QString dst2015 = QDir::temp().absolutePath()+"/vc_redist.x86.exe";
vcredistResource2015.copy(dst2015);
QProcess p2015;
p2015.start(dst2015);
p2015.waitForFinished(-1);

//QThread::sleep(1); //this line solves it

QFile rm15(dst2015);
rm15.setPermissions(QFile::ReadOther|QFile::WriteOther);
if (rm15.exists() && rm15.remove()) {
    qDebug() << "removed 2015";
}
else {
    qDebug() << rm15.errorString(); //Permission denied here
}
```

Comment: You should check the return value of `QProcess::waitForFinished`.

Comment: @G.M. return value is true

Comment: Does it make a difference if p2015 is destroyed before the attempt to delete the exe? (i.e. by using an extra block). Although the sleep() fixing it suggests that it doesn’t...

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I tried to enclose p2015 in a local scope {} block, calling .close() and .deleteLater() nothing really does anything.